# how to calculate $ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1\pm q^{2n-1}\right), \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1\pm q^{2n}\right)$

Tags: infinite-product

It is well known that we have the following pentagon number theorem by Euler:

$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{n}\right)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^nq^{\large \frac{3n^2-n}2}$.

However, how to calculate the following for $|q|<1$ :
$$(1) \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)$$

$$(2) \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{2n-1}\right)$$

$$(3) \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n}\right)$$

$$(4) \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{2n}\right)$$

Can you give some suggestions about them?

Comment: (3) should be straightforward.

Comment: @AnginaSeng  Yes, right.

Comment: 1) $\{{\rm odd}\} = \{{\rm all}\} \setminus \{{\rm even}\}$, 2, 3) trivial 4) $1+x = \frac{1 - x^2}{1 - x}$

Answer (score 1):

Four related infinite q-products can be expressed in
terms of the [Ramanujan theta function](https://oeis.org/A010815)
$\,f(-q) := (1-q^1)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)\cdots\,$  as follows:

[(A081362)](https://oeis.org/A081362) 
$$Q_3(q) := (1-q^1)(1-q^3)(1-q^5)\cdots = 
\frac{f(-q)}{f(-q^2)} .\tag{1}$$
[(A000700)](https://oeis.org/A000700)
$$Q_2(q) := (1+q^1)(1+q^3)(1+q^5)\cdots = 
\frac{f^2(-q^2)}{f(-q)f(-q^4)} .\tag{2}$$
[(A274719)](https://oeis.org/A274719) 
$$ Q_0(q) := (1-q^2)(1-q^4)(1-q^6)\cdots =
 f(-q^2) .\tag{3}$$ 
[(A035457)](https://oeis.org/A035457)
$$Q_1(q) := (1+q^2)(1+q^4)(1+q^6)\cdots = 
\frac{f(-q^4)}{f(-q^2)} .\tag{4}$$

Consult the linked  OEIS entries for some details on their
computation. They are all special cases of a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).
Consult the linked Wikipedia article for some details. The
[OEIS sequence A115977](https://oeis.org/A115977)
"Expansion of elliptic modular function lambda in powers of the nome q".
has some details and references.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.  Recently , I read one paper titled
'Modular equations and approximations to π' by Ramanujan, in which there are 
 some formulas :$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{2n-1}\right)=2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}(kk')^{-\frac{1}{12}}$$ and $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)= 2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}k^{-\frac{1}{12}}k'^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Especially, when $q=e^{-\pi}$, then we have $$\left(1+e^{-\pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-3 \pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-5 \pi  }\right) \cdots=2^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{-\pi   / 24}.  $$ But I donot understand these formula yet.

Comment: @ Somos  Ramanujan's paper in 1914  please see the link: [Modular equations and approximations to π](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf)

Comment: I do not know how to compute the $k$ and $k'$.

Comment: Note that $k':=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ and $m=k^2=\lambda(\tau)$ the [elliptic modular lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function).. I already know about the 1914 paper.

Comment: Great. But how to prove these formulas? Could you provide some suggestions?

Comment: @Dr.Jacob.Z.Lee In your question you asked "...how to calculate...". I suggest that If you have a specific formula you want to prove, ask it another question.