# how to prove these formulas about infinite product?

Tags: calculus, theta-functions, q-series, modular-function

Recently , I read one paper titled 'Modular equations and approximations to π' by Ramanujan, in which there are some formulas for $q=\pi i \tau$( where $\tau=x+yi, y>0$, hence $|q|<1)$ :

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{2n-1}\right)=2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}(kk')^{-\frac{1}{12}} ~~~  (1)$$

and 
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)= 2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}k^{-\frac{1}{12}}k'^{\frac{1}{6}} ~~~~(2)$$

where $k=k(\tau)$ is the Jacobi modulus，   $k^2(\tau)=\lambda(\tau)$, the elliptic modular function, and $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}.$

The following result can be calculated by Mathematica:
$$\left(1+e^{-\pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-3 \pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-5 \pi  }\right) \cdots=2^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{-\pi   / 24}.$$

But I do not know how to prove these formulas (1) and (2). I would appreciate if someone could give some suggestions.

Comment: What are $k$ and $k'$ here?

Comment: $k':=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ and $m=k^2=\lambda(\tau)$ the elliptic modular lambda function..

Comment: Right; so have you a $q$-series for $k$? for $k'$?

Comment: Ramanujan's paper in 1914 please see the link: [Modular equations and approximations to π](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf)

Comment: Please see the related [MSE question 3630948](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3630948) for some more background.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358015/how-to-prove-some-indentities-about-infinite-product a violation of site norms.

Comment: You can have a look at my series of blog posts starting with [this one](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html?m=0).

Comment: You need to know the fundamental relations between theta functions and elliptic integrals like $\vartheta_{3}^2(q)=2K/\pi$ and $k=\vartheta_{2}^2(q)/\vartheta_{3}^2(q), k'=\vartheta_{4}^2(q)/\vartheta _{3}^2(q)$. The key component is the product expansions of these theta functions. Combining such formulas one can easily get the identities you seek.

Comment: The theory of theta functions and elliptic integrals is very fascinating and at the same time made very complicated using complex analysis and abstract algebra techniques. Ramanujan instead relied on basic calculus and high school algebra to simplify these things a lot. You can check my [blog archive](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/p/archives.html?m=0) which contains a lot of posts on these topics. Also remember that this theory is time consuming and seductive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief outline of how these identities can be proved. The material is borrowed from my blog (linked in comments to question).

Let's start with a real number $k\in(0,1)$ called *modulus* and define a *complementary* modulus $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ and the complete elliptic integral of first kind: $$K(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\tag{1}$$ The numbers $K(k), K(k') $ are usually denoted by $K, K'$. The real surprise here is that given the values of $K,K'$ (they are not independent but are rather functions of $k$) it is possible to find the values of $k, k'$ via the magical formulas of Jacobi: $$k=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^2(q)}{\vartheta_{3}^2(q)}, k'=\frac{\vartheta_{4}^2(q)}{\vartheta_{3}^2(q)}\tag{2}$$ where $q=e^{-\pi K'/K} $ is the *nome* corresponding to modulus $k$ and
\begin{align}
\vartheta_{2}(q)&=\sum_{n=-\infty} ^{\infty} q^{(n+(1/2))^2}\notag\\
\vartheta_{3}(q)&=\sum_{n=-\infty} ^{\infty} q^{n^2}\notag\\
\vartheta_{4}(q)&=\vartheta_{3}(-q)\notag
\end{align}
are theta functions of Jacobi. The formulas $(2)$ can be proved using properties of elliptic integrals and series definitions of theta functions provided above. This has been done in [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html?m=0) and the [following post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0).

Another ingredient needed here is the [Jacobi triple product](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0) which allows us to obtain product representations for these theta functions. It can be stated as $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb {Z}} z^nq^{n^2}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n})(1+zq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})\tag{3}$$ for all complex numbers $z, q$ with $z\neq 0$ and $|q|<1$.

You can easily prove your identities in question via the use of $(2)$ and $(3)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This problem has been resolved in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358015/how-to-prove-some-identities-about-infinite-product)